# Harry’s stomach gave a horrible lurch. (is it a sound or a feeling?)

Tags: meaning

Excerpt from a Harry Potter book:

> Harry’s stomach gave a horrible lurch.

Does stomach lurch refers to a sound the stomach produces? Or is it a feeling in one's stomach?

Comment: Just google it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It refers to a feeling.

It's a reaction to something startling, and is not usually associated with any physical movement. Indeed, it is not usually felt in the actual stomach, but lower down.

Also be aware that the expression is often used metaphorically to indicate extreme surprise.

Comment: If people are nervous they may say they feel 'butterflies in their stomach'.